# Why does using elimination in a system of first order differential equations produce an incorrect result?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

For example, if I have the system,

$$
y'+y=3x \\
y'-y=x
$$
I could then use elimination to minus the top equation from the bottom one to get,

$$
2y=2x \\
y=x
$$

Which is obviously wrong as then, $1+x=3x$ which is wrong.

So why are you not able to use elimination in solving a system of first order differential equations?

Comment: Why should 2x = 1 be wrong?

Comment: What is the intended solution for this system?

Comment: But still the process of elimination has produced an incorrect function for y

Comment: @MichaelBurr I do not know myself

Comment: The general solution to y'+y=3x is \frac{\int \:e^{\int \:p\left(x\right)dx}q\left(x\right)dx+C}{e^{\int \:p\left(x\right)dx}}

Comment: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/linear-first-order-differential-equation-calculator/y'%2By%3D3x/?origin=enterkey

Comment: Observe that for the general solution $y=3(x-1)+ce^{-x}$, $y'=3-ce^{-x}$, so $y'-y=3x-6-2ce^{-x}$, which is not $x$ for any choice of constant $c$.

Comment: I believe that this gives you nonsense because the system is inconsistent.  If you were to try this with a consistent system (one where $y$ exists), the technique may work.  For example, if you try $y'+y=3x$ and $y'-y=3x-6$, elimination results in $y=3x-3$, which is a solution.

Comment: Okay, I understand. So, you can only use elimination where there is a (real) solution?

Comment: No, elimination is always valid. And it can show you that there is no solution.

Comment: But it shows that there is a solution... y=x.

Comment: Which doesn't fit with the original equations so isn't a solution of the system.

Comment: @DanielePilkington-Scimone See my answer. Your new system is not equivalent to your original system.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank you

Comment: "minus" is not a verb.  Use "subtract" as in "I could then use elimination to subtract the top equation from the bottom one to get,"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equivalence is really between these systems of equations
$$
\left\vert
\begin{matrix} 
y' + y = 3x \\
y' - y = x
\end{matrix}
\right\vert
\iff
\left\vert 
\begin{matrix}
y' + y = 3x \\
y = x
\end{matrix}
\right\vert
\iff
\left\vert 
\begin{matrix}
y' - y = x \\
y = x
\end{matrix}
\right\vert
$$
so your error is that you dropped one of the original equations, which leads to a larger set of solutions than it should.

However the above equivalence is holding:

The general solution of $y' + y = 3x$ is $y(x) = c \, e^{-x} + 3x -3$.

The general solution of $y' - y = x$ is $y(x) = c e^x-x-1$.

So the first system has no solution. As does the second system. And as does the third system. They all have the emtpy set as set of solutions.

Answer (score 4):

No problem using elimination, but your system is incompatible.

Comment: why is it incompatible?

Comment: Because these two equations have no common solution.

Comment: Why not? (y', y and x is the same value in both cases

Comment: @DanielePilkington-Scimone: please show me a common solution.

Comment: @DanielePilkington-Scimone Because you can not solve for $x$ in something like $x=x+1$.

Comment: @DanielePilkington-Scimone You've _proved_ there is no solution! Because you've shown that _if_ $y$ is a solution then $y=x$, but it's clear that $y=x$ is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

What the argument shows is that a differentiable function $y(x)$ can satisfy both equations only at a severely restricted set $S$ of $x$ values: with the possible exception of $x=1/2$, every point in $S$ is isolated.  In particular there is no open interval of $x$'s where both equations can hold.

Conversely, for any $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ whose set of non-isolated points is either $\lbrace 1/2 \rbrace$ or empty, there is a differentiable $y(x)$ satisying both equations for all $x \in S$.  The construction is to set $y(x)=x$ and $y'(x)=2x$ for all $x \in S$ and smoothly interpolate $y$ to the points outside $S$.

The converse shows that no further restriction on $S$ can be derived from the equations.